# What are the Trophy qualities, and what do they do?

Tags: sunless-sea

Recently I finally completed one of my captain's Ambitions (Father's Bones) and won the game. When I started a new captain and opened the Gazetteer, I noticed they had two new Accomplishments next to the Scion, called "Trophy: A Daguerrotype of a Memorial" and "Trophy: A Letter of Commendation". Are these for completing the game? Do they do anything, like the Scion? Are there other qualities that do similar things?

Answer (score 2):

Trophy qualities are awarded for finishing (or nearly finishing) the Ambitions. There is at least one Trophy per Ambition, and often more; unlike the Legacy qualities (An Ironclad Will, Scion, etc.) they do not have any gameplay effects.

The full list is (some spoilers follow):

- A Daguerrotype of a Memorial, for completing the Father's Bones Ambition in any way that results in a burial at home
- A Model Monster, for obtaining your Father's Bones as a street-urchin
- Not Quite Human, for completing the Father's Bones Ambition as a street-urchin by

  > turning into a zee-beast in a random event at zee instead of burying him in London
- A Letter of Commendation, for obtaining your Father's Bones as a poet
- A Shattered Coral Knife, for obtaining your Father's Bones as a soldier
- A Posthumous Medal, for obtaining your Father's Bones as a priest without having the Unaccountably Peckish quality
- A Glass of Teeth, for obtaining your Father's Bones as a priest while Unaccountably Peckish
- A Family Portrait, for obtaining your Father's Bones as a natural philosopher

  > actually for recruiting Your Father as an officer
- An Autographed Copy of the Zong of the Zee, for completing the Zong of the Zee Ambition*
- An Impossible Restaurant Bill, for completing the Wealth Ambition
- A Folded Flag, for completing the Kingdom Ambition
- The Lights of London, for completing the Go East Ambition after

  > telling the Exile that you'll "always return home"
- Restless, for completing the Go East Ambition after

  > telling the Exile that "the zee is [your] only home"
- Those Final Mountains, for completing the Go East Ambition after

  > telling the Exile that you "cannot rest until you've crossed the last horizon"

*The Autographed Copy shows up as a Curiosity, not an Accomplishment.